# Does Razzle v4 support React 18?

Tags: reactjs, razzle

I have React project that created by Razzle v3 and React 16, my plan to upgrade project to use React 18. I upgrade the packages but I'm notice many of issues related `.bablrc` and `localhost:3000` running without any content "similar to internet disconnected"

I tried to follow existing project using latest Razzle and used same babel version, but I still have the same issue.

My `.babelrc` file:

```json
{
  "presets": ["razzle/babel"],
  "plugins": ["styled-components"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "only": ["src"],
      "plugins": [
        "lodash",
        "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "Linz-Heritage-Angus",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "Linz Heritage Angus",
  "author": "Alpha Solutions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ./src",
    "build": "razzle build",
    "test": "razzle test --env=jsdom",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node build/server.js",
    "start:dev": "razzle start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.9.2",
    "@fluentui/react-icons": "1.1.117",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@lagunovsky/redux-react-router": "^4.3.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "final-form": "^4.20.1",
    "final-form-focus": "^1.1.2",
    "fontfaceobserver": "2.0.13",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.0.1",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "invariant": "2.2.4",
    "isemail": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.20",
    "mobile-device-detect": "^0.4.3",
    "polished": "^3.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0",
    "razzle": "^4.2.18",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cool-onclickoutside": "^1.4.8",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.16.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-final-form": "^6.5.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0-beta",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-intl": "^6.4.7",
    "react-lazyload": "github:twobin/react-lazyload",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router": "^6.16.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-select": "^5.7.4",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-sticky-el": "^2.0.5",
    "react-tippy": "^1.4.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.10",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sanitize.css": "4.1.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "styled-normalize": "^8.0.7",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@arkweid/lefthook": "^0.7.2",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.22.5",
    "@eslint-kit/base": "^1.0.0",
    "@eslint-kit/prettier": "^1.0.0",
    "@eslint-kit/react": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.11.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "7.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^48.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```